# php вывод названий файлов в директории в чекбокс

Tags: php, html, html5

Добрый день, есть такой вот скрипт:

```
<?php
$dir = '../';

$f = scandir($dir);

foreach ($f as $file){
    if(preg_match('/\.(php)/', $file)){
        echo $file.'<br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

как по нему видно он серфит и выводит все php файлы в директории
подскажите как сделать так, что-бы эти файлы выводились в чекбокс?

```
   <p>VIBIRITE STRANICI DLYA DELETe</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="НА"> НА </p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="Каждый"> Каждый</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="Файл"> Файл</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="Свой"> Свой </p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="Инпут"> Инпут</p>
```

т.е. например в папке 6 файлов, скриптом они выводятся без проблем в цикле, но как мне сделать так, что-бы выводить их не с помощью `echo` в столбик через `br`, а каждый файл в свой инпут чекбокса. Суть в том, что смотрятся файлы в директории вывод которых я хочу сделать через чекбокс, что-бы можно было отметить и удалить нужные файлы

Comment: echo '<input type=checkbox value=' . $file . '>'. $file; не?

Comment: это конечно да. но,  названий файлов больше чем одно и на каждое нужен свой чекбокс и

Comment: Ну и поставте это в цикл и чекбоксов будет столько сколько файлов.

Comment: лол чет я дибил. спасибо